# undefined variable in views in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here my controller is

```
class Admin extends CI_Controller { 


function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}
public function index($msg = NULL) {
     $data['msg'] = $msg;

    $this->load->view('pages/sign-in');

}
 public function process(){
    // Load the model
    $this->load->model('admin/Admin_model');
    // Validate the user can login
    $result = $this->Admin_model->validate();
    // Now we verify the result
    if(! $result){
        // If user did not validate, then show them login page again
        $msg = '<font color=red>Invalid username and/or password.</font><br />';
        $this->index($msg);
    }else{
        // If user did validate, 
        // Send them to members area
        redirect(base_url().'index.php/home');
    }        
}
```

and here is view file i  am using:

```
if(! is_null($msg)) echo $msg;
```

it shows

> undefined variable $msg

Comment: And what route are you using to access the index controller?

Comment: Feeding in any args?

Comment: http://betaonetesting.com/watch_new/index.php/admin

Comment: `$this->load->view('pages/sign-in', $data);` i.e. pass the view some data, then the view will have access to some data.

Answer (score 2):

You are not passing the data array into your view. Try this:

```
$this->load->view('pages/sign-in', $data);
```